# How to move a key to up level from nested JSON object using JOLT Transformation

Tags: json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I want to do a JOLT Transformation and shift the key inside a nested JSON object to uplevel.

Here is my **input JSON**:

```json
[
  {
    "deviceNumber": "1287391731_city",
    "country": {
      "State": [
        {
          "Priority": "MEDIUM",
          "City": {
            "Town": [
              {
                "unit": "",
                "type": "",
                "value": "Mumbai",
                "key": "District1"
              },
              {
                "unit": "",
                "type": "",
                "value": "Delhi",
                "key": "District2"
              },
              {
                "unit": "",
                "type": "",
                "value": "2",
                "key": "DistrictCount"
              }
            ]
          },
          "description": "describe the subcategory"
        }
      ]
    },
    "location": "8.21311,76.018231"
  },
  {
    "deviceNumber": "1287391731_city",
    "country": {
      "State": [
        {
          "Priority": "MEDIUM",
          "City": {
            "Town": [
              {
                "unit": "",
                "type": "",
                "value": "Bangalore",
                "key": "District1"
              },
              {
                "unit": "",
                "type": "",
                "value": "Chennai",
                "key": "District2"
              },
              {
                "unit": "",
                "type": "",
                "value": "2",
                "key": "DistrictCount"
              }
            ]
          },
          "description": "describe the subcategory"
        }
      ]
    },
    "location": "8.21311,76.018231"
  },
  {
    "deviceNumber": "1287391731_city",
    "country": {
      "State": [
        {
          "Priority": "MEDIUM",
          "City": {
            "Town": [
              {
                "unit": "",
                "type": "",
                "value": "Ahmedabad",
                "key": "District1"
              },
              {
                "unit": "",
                "type": "",
                "value": "Kolkata",
                "key": "District2"
              },
              {
                "unit": "",
                "type": "",
                "value": "2",
                "key": "DistrictCount"
              }
            ]
          },
          "description": "describe the subcategory"
        }
      ]
    },
    "location": "8.21311,76.018231"
  }
]
```

Here is the **expected Output**:

```json
[
  {
    "@context": "https://my_context.in",
    "type": [
      "CITYVIEW"
    ],
    "deviceNumber": "1287391731_city",
    "DistrictCount": 2,
    "location": "8.21311,76.018231",
    "District1": {
      "NormalValue": "Delhi"
    },
    "District2": {
      "NormalValue": "Mumbai"
    }
  },
  {
    "@context": "https://my_context.in",
    "type": [
      "CITYVIEW"
    ],
    "deviceNumber": "1287391731_city",
    "DistrictCount": 2,
    "location": "8.21311,76.018231",
    "District1": {
      "NormalValue": "Bangalore"
    },
    "District2": {
      "NormalValue": "Chennai"
    }
  },
  {
    "@context": "https://my_context.in",
    "type": [
      "CITYVIEW"
    ],
    "deviceNumber": "1287391731_city",
    "DistrictCount": 2,
    "location": "8.21311,76.018231",
    "District1": {
      "NormalValue": "Ahmedabad"
    },
    "District2": {
      "NormalValue": "Kolkata"
    }
  }
]
```

Here `districtCount` is shifted uplevel and the value is shown as an integer. Type and context are default values and be created using default operation. District1 and District2 can be shifted using the following spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "country": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": ""
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "value": "@(1,key).NormalValue"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This is the output I am getting:

```json
{
  "District1": {
    "NormalValue": "Mumbai"
  },
  "District2": {
    "NormalValue": "Delhi"
  },
  "DistrictCount": {
    "NormalValue": "2"
  }
}
```

Could you please help me in writing the spec for JOLT transformation to get the expected output?

Comment: Hi James, can you please tell why did you need to delete the last question

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "#https:\//my_context.in": "[&1].\\@context",
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "type": "[&1].&[]",
        "country": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "*": {
                    "*": {
                      "DistrictCount": {
                        "@(2,value)": "[&9].@2"
                      },
                      "District*": {
                        "@(2,value)": "[&9].@2.NormalValue"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "DistrictCount": "=toInteger"
      }
    }
  }
]
```